# Running Totals Results Incorrect

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, t-sql

I have a cursor that collects information from a different table and then updates the summary,here is the code snippet that is giving me a headache.

I am trying to update the summary table by input the correct Males and Females information that will add up to the total numbers of patients.

```
BEGIN
    Set @MaleId =154
    set @Femaleid =655

    if @Category =@MaleId
    begin
        set @Males = @Value
    end
    if @Category = @Femaleid
    begin
        set @CummFemalesOnHaart =@Value
    end 

    Update Stats
       set Males =@Malest,Females =@Females
     where
           Category =@Category and
           periodType =@PeriodType AND StartDate =@Startdate and EndDate =@enddate
```

Problem:

### The results are inaccurate

```
organisation PeriodType  StartDate   EndDate     Deaths  Patients  Males  Females
------------ ----------  ----------  ----------  ------  --------  -----  -------
34           Monthly     2010-04-01  2010-04-30  NULL    6843      896    463
34           Monthly     2010-04-01  2010-04-30  NULL    10041     896    463
34           Monthly     2010-05-01  2010-05-31  NULL    10255     898    463 
34           Monthly     2010-05-01  2010-05-31  NULL    7086      898    461
34           Monthly     2010-06-01  2010-06-30  NULL    10344     922    461
36           Monthly     2010-03-01  2010-03-31  NULL    4317      1054   470
36           Monthly     2010-03-01  2010-03-31  NULL    5756      896    470
36           Monthly     2010-04-01  2010-04-30  NULL    4308      896    463
36           Monthly     2010-04-01  2010-04-30  NULL    5783      896    463
```

The Males and Female should only update single rows that add up to the total number of patiens
e,g

```
Patients  Males  Females
--------  -----  -------
41        21     20
```

Any ideas?

Just to clarify a bit more

/*Query Table*/

```
organisation  PeriodType  StartDate   EndDate     Males  Females 
------------  ----------  ----------  ----------  -----  -------
34            Monthly     01-02-2012  01-02-2012  220    205
34            Monthly     01-02-2012  01-02-2012  30     105
```

/*Update statetement */

```
Update Stats 
   set Males =@Malest,Females =@Females 
 where 
       --Category =@Category and 
       periodType =@PeriodType AND StartDate =@Startdate and EndDate =@enddate
```

Stats Table /*Before Input*/

```
organisation PeriodType  StartDate   EndDate     Deaths  Patients  Males  Females
------------ ----------  ----------  ----------  ------  --------  -----  -------
34           Monthly     01-02-2012  01-02-2012  0       425       null   null
34           Monthly     01-02-2012  01-02-2012  25      null      null   null   
34           Monthly     01-02-2012  01-02-2012  5       null      null   null 
34           Monthly     01-02-2012  01-02-2012  5       135       null   null
```

/*if you look at closely at the rows the period type,startdate,enddate are the same so I don't want the update values  to affect any other row besides the ones with the Patients Totals*/

Stats Table /* Output */

```
organisation PeriodType  StartDate   EndDate     Deaths  Patients  Males  Females
------------ ----------  ----------  ----------  ------  --------  -----  -------
34           Monthly     01-02-2012  01-02-2012  0       425       220    205
34           Monthly     01-02-2012  01-02-2012  25      null      null   null   
34           Monthly     01-02-2012  01-02-2012  5       null      null   null 
34           Monthly     01-02-2012  01-02-2012  5       135       30     105
```

I hope this gives more information

Comment: To make the code stand out, edit your question, highlight the code, then press this button `{}`, it's the 5th button from **B**, ***I, ...***. You can do the same on the results

Comment: It would be a lot easier to follow if you used the *same* sample data throughout. First show us the original data. Then show the exact same records after the update (ie "wrong" results). And finally, what the data *should* be instead - and why.

Answer (score 1):

What you are proposing, from what I can see, will always run the risk of having incorrect data assigned.  What happens when you have two records, one with patients 500 (males 250 and females 250) and another with patients 500 (but males 300 and females 200)?

There is no clear distinction which record totals to then use, and you'll end up with possible multiple updates with incorrect data.

That being said, I think what you should do is the following.

1. create a CTE which selects the patients from stats table, and males / females from query table, where patients = (males + females)
2. Run the update statement on the stats table, using values from the CTE joined on patients total.

This should, as far as I can understand, give a solution to what you're after.

You can read more about CTE's here: [MSDN Common Table Expressions](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175972.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

I'm not entirely sure I understand your question... but think this is what you are after?

```
UPDATE Stats
SET Males = (SELECT COUNT(*) From <queryTable> WHERE Category = @MaleId and periodType =@PeriodType AND StartDate =@Startdate and EndDate =@enddate)
,SET Females = (SELECT COUNT(*) From <queryTable> WHERE Category = @FemaleId and periodType =@PeriodType AND StartDate =@Startdate and EndDate =@enddate)
```

Hope it helps!

Comment: Thank you for your response,I have added more information that might give more clarity

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure I understand the question either. But it sounds like you are saying there can be multiple records having the same `periodType`, `startDate` and `endDate`, but a different number of `Patients`. You wish to ensure the query only updates records where the total number of `Patients` matches the total you calculated ie total = `@Males + @Females`.

If that is correct, add a filter on the Patients value:

```
    UPDATE Stats 
    SET    Males = @Males,
           Females = @Females 
    WHERE  Category = @Category 
    AND    periodType = @PeriodType 
    AND    StartDate = @Startdate 
    AND    EndDate = @enddate 
    AND    Patients = (@Males + @Females)
```

Though as an aside, cursors generally tend to be less efficient than set based alternatives ..